# Java Hashmap store only value of a particular type in key

Tags: java, reflection, types

I am looking at creating a Hashmap class which allows me to store keys and values. However, the value can only be stored if it matches a specific type, and the type is dependent on the *runtime value* of the key. For example, if the key is `EMAIL(String.class)`, then the stored value should be of type `String`.

I have following custom ENUM:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TDD,
    BDD,
    SHIFT_RIGHT,
    SHIFT_LEFT;
}
```

I have created following class :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {

    private static final Map<ValidKeys, Object> sessionData = new HashMap<>();

    public enum ValidKeys {
        EMAIL(String.class),
        PASSWORD(String.class),
        FIRST_NAME(String.class),
        LAST_NAME(String.class),
        CONDITION(TestEnum.class);

        private Class type;
        private boolean isList;
        private Pattern pattern;

        ValidKeys(Class<?> type, boolean isList) {
            this.type = type;
            this.isList = isList;
        }

        ValidKeys(Class<?> type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public <T> void setData(ValidKeys key, T value) {
        sessionData.put(key,value);
    }


    public Object getData(ValidKeys key) {
        return key.type.cast(sessionData.get(key));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        t.setData(ValidKeys.CONDITION,TestEnum.TDD);
        System.out.println(t.getData(ValidKeys.CONDITION));
    }
}
```

I would like to use methods such as `setData` and `getData` and store values into `sessionData`. Also, I want to ensure if the value is a list of objects then thats stored properly as well.

I am also struggling to avoid toString basically I need a generic getData which can work without type casting.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Let me clarify, you want the value to be dependent from the key, am I right? That means if I have a key of type `Foo`, then only `Bar` object can be stored, or if the key is `Fuu`, then the only allowed value type will be `Baz`. For simple maps with value and key of specific types, you can go just with a `HashMap<Foo, Bar>` or `HashMap<Fuu, Baz>`.

Comment: Thanks @itachi - that's correct. If the key is Foo, then only Bar object can be stored.

Comment: So, what prevents you from declaring your hash map as `HashMap<Foo, Bar>`?

Comment: Ever occurred to you to read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), or to learn about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, it looks like he wants to have a map, that can hold mixed key/value pair of any type, but the type check will be performed later while putting something to this map. It's like `HashMap<Object, Object>` with custom "put".

Comment: @itachi Could be. Sounds a bit speculative, tbh. Instead of speculating, I'd rather wait and see whether OP clarifies the question.

Comment: @JavaMan There's a little gray `edit` button in the lower left corner under the question. I'd suggest to use that instead of adding code in comments. In the posting, you have more space and much better support for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, looks better. Still not quite clear what `TDD` is supposed to mean in this context, it doesn't appear in the enumeration. Any chance to extend it into a [mcve], or at least into code that contains some pseudocode here and there?

Comment: Oh, great. The code compiles, that's nice. What did you attempt with the `String.class` part there? Unless you do something weird with classloaders, there will be only one `String` class, what's the point of requiring it as argument? It's still not clear what `TDD` is supposed to be, and how it relates to the code.

Comment: String.class is just a example type however, I am trying to accommodate scenario where the value type can be a custom object. Apologies @AndreyTyukin if my liking for TDD confused you it was just a weird example.

Comment: @JavaMan Ah, ok, I see now. You are trying to save runtime type-tags in the keys of the hash map, and those type-tags have to be able to differentiate between various types and lists of other types. Similar to what Guice's [`TypeLiteral`s](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) are doing.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - Have a look at the code again. I have got a simple example running now. I just love the way guice handle some of the stuff, but am forced to use Spring DI in my project. With regards to the working example, I hate the type casting during SOUT and am still trying to get my head around handling list of type.

Comment: @JavaMan: It sounds like what you're looking for is Josh Bloch's *Typesafe Hetrogenous Container* idea. The concept and sample code are in the book *Effective Java*, which I highly recommend.

Comment: @JavaMan: In this specific case, what I think you're looking for is `return key.type.cast(sessionData.get(key));`. Since you have a type token, the cast is for all intents and purposes a real checked one, and so there is no unchecked warning.

Comment: Oh, but `key.type.cast()` won't work if the type field is a raw type. Make sure to use `Class<?>` instead of raw `Class`, so that `cast` will actually return the type of the class instead of the erased type (which is just `Object` in this case).

Comment: @DanielPryden - I have got the get method working with Object and have attached the latest code with this thread. Have a look if you agree with the solution or you can think of something better. Many thanks everyone for your patience and help. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a particular pattern I've seen used for this sort of thing, which is a variant of Bloch's Typesafe Heterogenous Container pattern. I don't know if it has a name on its own or not, but for lack of a better name I'll call it Typesafe Enumerated Lookup Keys.

Basically, a problem that I've seen arise in various contexts is where you want a dynamic set of key/value pairs, where a particular subset of keys are "well-known" with predefined semantics. Additionally, each key is associated with a particular type.

The "obvious" solution is to use an enum. For example, you could do:

```
public enum LookupKey { FOO, BAR }

public final class Repository {
    private final Map<LookupKey, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(LookupKey key, Object value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object get(LookupKey key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but the obvious drawback is that now you need to cast everywhere. For example, suppose you know that `LookupKey.FOO` always has a `String` value, and `LookupKey.BAR` always has an `Integer` value. How do you enforce that? With this implementation, you can't.

Also: with this implementation, the set of keys is fixed by the enum. You can't add new ones at runtime. For some applications that's an advantage, but in other cases you really do want to allow new keys in certain cases.

The solution to both these problems is basically the same one: make `LookupKey` a first-class entity, not just an enum. For example:

```
/**
 * A key that knows its own name and type.
 */
public final class LookupKey<T> {
    // These are the "enumerated" keys:
    public static final LookupKey<String> FOO = new LookupKey<>("FOO", String.class);
    public static final LookupKey<Integer> BAR = new LookupKey<>("BAR", Integer.class);

    private final String name;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public LookupKey(String name, Class<T> type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this key.
     */
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Cast an arbitrary object to the type of this key.
     * 
     * @param object an arbitrary object, retrieved from a Map for example.
     * @throws ClassCastException if the argument is the wrong type.
     */
    public T cast(Object object) {
        return type.cast(object);
    }

    // not shown: equals() and hashCode() implementations
}
```

This gets us most of the way there already. You can refer to `LookupKey.FOO` and `LookupKey.BAR` and they behave like you would expect, but they also know the corresponding looked-up type. And you can also define your own keys by creating new instances of `LookupKey`.

If we want to implement some nice enum-like abilities like the static `values()` method, we just need to add a registry. As a bonus, we don't even need `equals()` and `hashCode()` if we add a registry, since we can just compare lookup keys by identity now.

Here's what the class ends up looking like:

```
/**
 * A key that knows its own name and type.
 */
public final class LookupKey<T> {
    // This is the registry of all known keys.
    // (It needs to be declared first because the create() function needs it.)
    private static final Map<String, LookupKey<?>> knownKeys = new HashMap<>();

    // These are the "enumerated" keys:
    public static final LookupKey<String> FOO = create("FOO", String.class);
    public static final LookupKey<Integer> BAR = create("BAR", Integer.class);


    /**
     * Create and register a new key. If a key with the same name and type
     * already exists, it is returned instead (Flywheel Pattern).
     *
     * @param name A name to uniquely identify this key.
     * @param type The type of data associated with this key.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if a key with the same name but a different
     *     type was already registered.
     */
    public static <T> LookupKey<T> create(String name, Class<T> type) {
        synchronized (knownKeys) {
            LookupKey<?> existing = knownKeys.get(name);
            if (existing != null) {
                if (existing.type != type) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Incompatible definition of " + name);
                }
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // our invariant ensures this is safe
                LookupKey<T> uncheckedCast = (LookupKey<T>) existing;
                return uncheckedCast;
            }
            LookupKey<T> key = new LookupKey<>(name, type);
            knownKeys.put(name, key);
            return key;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of all the currently known lookup keys.
     */
    public static List<LookupKey<?>> values() {
        synchronized (knownKeys) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(
                    new ArrayList<>(knownKeys.values()));
        }
    }

    private final String name;
    private final Class<T> type;

    // Private constructor. Only the create method should call this.
    private LookupKey(String name, Class<T> type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this key.
     */
    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Cast an arbitrary object to the type of this key.
     * 
     * @param object an arbitrary object, retrieved from a Map for example.
     * @throws ClassCastException if the argument is the wrong type.
     */
    public T cast(Object object) {
        return type.cast(object);
    }
}
```

Now `LookupKey.values()` works more or less like an enum would. You can also add your own keys, and `values()` will return them afterward:

```
LookupKey<Double> myKey = LookupKey.create("CUSTOM_DATA", Double.class);
```

Once you have this `LookupKey` class, you can now implement a typesafe repository that uses these keys for lookup:

```
/**
 * A repository of data that can be looked up using a {@link LookupKey}.
 */
public final class Repository {
    private final Map<LookupKey<?>, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Set a value in the repository.
     *
     * @param <T> The type of data that is being stored.
     * @param key The key that identifies the value.
     * @param value The corresponding value.
     */
    public <T> void put(LookupKey<T> key, T value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a value from this repository.
     *
     * @param <T> The type of the value identified by the key.
     * @param key The key that identifies the desired value.
     */
    public <T> T get(LookupKey<T> key) {
        return key.cast(data.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Pryden, looks really cool and seems to have nailed the issue around Object / explicit casting. Awesome, Cheers !!

Comment: A quick one, I have no idea why I see a NPE for KnownKeys in create method. I have resolved it by initialising it again in the create method, but am not sure if that's correct. Pointers?

Comment: My bad, I had it laid out differently before and I reorganized the code when I posted it here. The `knownKeys` map needs to be declared *before* the "enumerated" values, since static fields are initialized in lexical order. I'll update the answer to show this. (As you point out, the other way to solve this is to initialize it lazily in the `create` method, but then it can't be `final`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel Pryden for responding to my comment. I should have picked it up yesterday whilst debugging but just didn't stuck me. Awesome, cheers !!!